# Indíce do primeiro número negativo de um vetor

Tags: c, array, booleano

Tenho que fazer um programa em C que salve o indice do primeiro numero negativo, porem não estou conseguindo fazer.
A Questão é essa ai de baixo:

Elabore um programa em C que entre com 5 números inteiros em um vetor A, e imprima o índice do primeiro número negativo, se houver. Caso não existam números negativos, imprimir a seguinte mensagem “Negativo não encontrado".

Tentei varias vezes mas nenhuma deu certo, podem me ajudar? O codigo ta assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

main(){

bool b = true;
int a[5],i, neg[5],n;

for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
printf ("Digite o numero inteiro para o vetor A[%d]: ",i);
scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    for (n=0;n<5;n++){
        if (a[i]<0 == b){
            neg[n]=i;
        }
    }
}

if (neg[0]<0){

    printf ("o indice do primeiro numero negativo e A[%d]", neg[0]);
}
else
    printf ("Nao tem numero negativo. ");

getchar ();
}
```

Tenho que mostrar o indice somente do primeiro numero negativo, porem se o primeiro numero negativo tiver no A[4], por exemplo, não funciona. So funcionia se o numero negativo aparecer no a[0]

Comment: edite a questão e adicione o código que está tentando...

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo para ver se consegue me ajudar

Answer (score 2):

É uma tarefa bem simples, não é necessário usar uma variável booleana para isso. Simplesmente preencha o vetor e leia-o novamente.

Tente identar e organizar mais seu código e use práticas corretas de programação. Não use o `main()` sem um método, normalmente declaramos como `int main()` ou se quiser argumentos use `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`. Sempre use um retorno para o `main`, normalmente usamos o `return 0` para indicar sucesso e o `return 1` para indicar uma falha.

O uso do `fflush(stdin)` foi para limpar o buffer de entrada para evitar que o `getchar()` "sugue" o último valor entrado pelo usuário e passe em branco, sem pausar a execução.

Dei uma reformulada em seu código, dê uma olhada:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int A[5];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o numero inteiro para o vetor A[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < 0)
        {
            printf("O indice do primeiro numero negativo e: A[%d]", A[i]);
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Nao tem numero negativo.");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Como pode ver, o primeiro número negativo que ele encontrar ele vai exibir e sair do programa. Se ele não encontrar nenhum número negativo ele irá continuar a execução e irá exibir a mensagem final.

Simplesmente uma comparação para saber se o número é menor do que 0.

Mas se ainda quiser usar o método booleano:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int A[5], N;
    bool isNegative = false;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o numero inteiro para o vetor A[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < 0)
        {
            N = A[i];
            isNegative = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isNegative == true)
    {
        printf("O indice do primeiro numero negativo e: A[%d]", N);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nao tem numero negativo.");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Com o método booleano foi declarada uma variável `isNegative` que inicialmente recebe o valor `false` e se for detectado um número negativo ela se transforma em `true`, o inteiro `N` pega o valor do índice negativo e quebra o laço de execução com o `break` pois não será necessário percorrer o resto do vetor.

Após isso ele verifica se a variável `isNegative` é verdadeira ou falsa e dá a resposta ao usuário com base nisso.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, pelo que entendi vamos lá. Você coloca cinco número em um vetor e depois verifica se existe negativos?

Pulando a parte de colocar valores no vetor, olhe se isto lhe ajuda.

for(contador = 0; contador < sizeof(vetor); contador++)
{
    if(vetor[contador] < 0){
        printf("Numero negativo", contador);
    }
}

...neste caso ele lhe mostrará, porém pode melhorar colocando um contador de fora dentro do if onde cada vez que o if for verdadeiro você conta quantos numero negativos existem.

Comment: `sizeof(vetor)` nao indica o numero de elementos do vetor.

Comment: Então, tenho que mostrar somente o indice do primeiro numero negativo, porem nao to conseguindo fazer isso com uma variaveel booleana.